# Python List -- ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' '

Tags: python, string, list, integer, list-comprehension

I have tried to use both loops as well as list comprehension. Both are unable to parse the integers even though i am trying to convert the numbers into int in a list.

```
student_scores = input("Input a list of student scores.")
print(student_scores)
for n in range(0, len(student_scores)):
    student_scores[n] = int(student_scores[n])
print(student_scores)


student_score = [int(i) for i in student_scores]

highest_score = 0
for score in student_score:
    if score > highest_score:
        highest_score = score
print(f"The highest score in the class is {highest_score}")
```

Comment: what is the value that you entred into this code ?

Comment: It's because you are calling `int()` on each character in the string, including the _spaces in between the numbers_.

Comment: What are you typing in?  Is it a list like "12 34 56"?  Then you're calling `int()` on each individual character, and `int(' ')` is going to fail.  Likewise if it's got commas.  You need to use `student_scores.split()` [look at documentation for arguments] to break it up into proper pieces.

Answer (score 2):

you never separate the input which is a string by default.  what is your delimiter?

```py
student_scores = input("Input a list of student scores.")
student_scores = student_scores.split(',') if ',' in student_scores else student_scores.split()
student_scores = list(map(int, student_scores))
print(student_scores)

highest_score = max(student_scores)
print(f"The highest score in the class is {highest_score}")
```

Answer (score 0):

I added .split() at the end of the input question and was able to resolve the issue. thx for the responses